# Nominalization of "impoverished"

Tags: nominalizations

Is there any rule stating what kind of adjectives can be nominalized (i.e. used as nouns)? I did some googling but could not find any examples of "impoverished" being used as a noun (e.g. housing for the impoverished)
(whereas I could find a lot of examples of adjectives like "poor" being used as a noun, e.g. housing for the poor. Most dictionaries even have an entry of "poor" as a noun)

Comment: Nearly all nouns which can apply to people can be nominalized, in the sense of "the poor" meaning "the poor people", and "impoverished" is no exception. Google "the impoverished are", and you'll find lots of examples.

Comment: Disproportionate numbers of **the impoverished** live in units which are lacking in the basic amenities , which are in bad physical condition , and which constitute a serious threat to the health and safety of their occupants .  https://www.google.com/books/edition/Committee_Prints/KGYOAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22the+impoverished%22&pg=RA7-PA194&printsec=frontcover

Comment: It's not about nominalisation, since the adjective "poor" doesn't become a noun in "the poor", but remains an adjective. "The poor" is thus a fused modifier-head NP, where the adjective "poor" is simultaneously head and modifier in the NP.

Answer (score -4):

These are not nouns as

a) They don't have the range of inflections common to nouns:

> *the poors are not happy
>
> *the poor's condition is pitiable

b) They are modified by adverbs:

> the **very** poor

c) They cannot be used separately from the definite article:

> *I met a poor yesterday
>
> *I met poor yesterday
>
> *Those poor need some help

They are adjectives that may be used as fused-heads with the understood head noun (people) omitted when the definite article is present.

There is a relatively wide range of modifiers that can appear in a fused head construction with the head noun left understood through context(CaGEL p415-417):

> a) Determinatives
>
> > i This copy is defective but [the other **two**] are fine.
> >
> > ii I’ve corrected most of the mistakes but [these **few** here] are
> >     still to be done.
> >
> > iii I didn’t like it myself, but I respect the views of [the **many**
> >     who did].
>
> b) Superlatives and Definite Comparatives
>
> > i I went up that skyscraper in Boston, but [the **tallest**] is in
> >     Chicago.
> >
> > ii There are two sisters, but [the **elder**] is already married.
> >
> > iii *Hugo has a big house, but Karl has [a **bigger**].
>
> c) Ordinal Adjectives
>
> > i The first student wanted to take linguistics, but [the **second**]
> >     did not.
> >
> > ii I wanted to catch the next train, because [the **last**] will be
> >     too late.
> >
> > iii After having a first child, I didn’t want[a **second**].
>
> d) Modifiers denoting color, provenance, or composition
>
> > i Henrietta likes red shirts, and I like [**blue**].
> >
> > ii Knut wanted the purple wallpaper, but I wanted [the **mauve**].
> >
> > iii Henrietta likes Russian vodka, and I like [**Polish**].
> >
> > iv Knut wanted the French caterers, but I wanted [the **Italian**].
> >
> > v I prefer cotton shirts to [**nylon**].
> >
> > vi Knut likes malt whisky, but I prefer [**blended**].
>
> The NPs here are either bare or have a definite determiner; there is
>   significant loss of acceptability when the determiner is indefinite:
>
> > i ? Harvey bought a red shirt and I bought [a **blue**].
> >
> > ii ? I bought some Chinese food rather than [some **Indian**],
> >
> > iii ? I bought a cotton shirt rather than [a **nylon**].
>
> e) Adjectives denoting basic physical properties such as age and size
>
> > i Lucie likes young dogs, but I prefer[**old**].
> >
> > ii Lucie likes big dogs, but I prefer [**small**].
>
> f) Modifier-heads with special interpretations
>
> > [The **French**] do these differently from [the Dutch].
> >
> > [The **rich**] cannot enter the kingdom of Heaven.
> >
> > How will the new system affect [the very **poor**]?
> >
> > We are going to attempt [the utterly **impossible**].
> >
> > This is verging on [the **immoral**].
> >
> > They like to swim in [the **nude**].
>
> The NPs are determined by the definite article - we couldn’t even
>   substitute a demonstrative: *these very poor. This subtype includes
>   adjectives based on past participle forms or similar denominal
>   derivatives in -ed: *the disadvantaged*, *the intellectually gifted*, *the
>   unemployed*, *the hard-hearted*, and so on.

In summary, there is no simple rule to separate what can and cannot be used as a fused-head, but any of the above, or similar, would be acceptable.

Comment: So *police* is not a noun, either? Let's check your conditions on it: *the polices are investigating, *the police's equipment needs te be replaced, *I met a police yesterday. Yes, [police](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/police) cannot be a noun.

Comment: Your answer is correct. "Poor" belongs to the word class 'adjective' (as in "poor people"), and it retains its adjective status in the noun phrase "the poor", interpreted as "poor people". So we have an NP with an adjective as fused modifier-head.

Comment: @BillJ: Regardless of *poor* is classified as an adjective or a noun, this "answer" completely fails to answer the OP's actual question, which was: which adjectives can be made to do this? This should be a comment.

Comment: _police_ has a genitive case inflection - _the police's equipment_ is quite acceptable as a google search will prove. Also, _police_ may be used without the definite article as in _After his arrest, he was questioned by local police and also members of Scotland Yard_. It also cannot be modified by adverbs, which _poor_ can.

Comment: @PeterShor It makes a valid point about nominalisation, unlike your first comment above, which is wrong by the way, since unlike "poor" "police" is not an adjective.  Why don't you post an answer yourself instead of trolling other people's answers